# Проблема маршрутиризации MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

При попытке вызова действия GetUser контроллера Account которое возвращает частичное представление, пишет что такого действия нету в этом контроллере, хотя оно есть.

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using ChudoPechkaLib.Models;
@model ChudoPechkaLib.Models.Group
@section ScriptAndStyle{
}
<div>
    <div>
        <hr />
        <span>Автор</span>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div id="=AuthorSection">
        @{Html.RenderAction("GetUser", "Account", new { login = Model.Author.User.Login });//Вызов действия контроллера}
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <hr />
        <span>Участники</span>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Контроллер

```
    public class AccountController : ChudoPechka.Controllers.Base.BaseController
{
    // GET: Account
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        if (!Auth.IsAuthentication)
            return View();
        else
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (!Auth.IsAuthentication)
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);
            else
            {
                Auth.RegisterUser(model);
                return Redirect(Url.Action("LoginIn"));
            }
        else
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoginIn()
    {
        if (Auth.IsAuthentication)
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginIn(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (!Auth.IsAuthentication)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && Auth.LoginIn(model.Login, model.Password))
                return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));

            ModelState.AddModelError("Login", "Неверный логин или пароль");

            return View(model);
        }
        else
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoginOut()
    {
        Auth.LoginOut();
        return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Recovery()
    {
        if (Auth.IsAuthentication)
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Recovery(RecoveryModel model)
    {
        if (Auth.IsAuthentication)
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();
            else if (Auth.UpdatePassword(model.login, model.newPass, model.responseQuestion))
                return Redirect(Url.Action("LoginIn"));

            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Неверный ответ, попробуйте ещё.");
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователь не найден, попробуйте ещё.");
        }
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUserToRecovery(string login)
    {
        User usr;
        if (Auth.GetUser(login, out usr))
            return View(usr);
        else
            return new ChudoPechka.Controllers.Base.PartialViewResult("Пользователь с логином не найден");

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUser(string login)//Вот он сам контроллер
    {
        User usr;
        if (Auth.GetUser(login, out usr))
            return View(usr);
        else
            return new ChudoPechka.Controllers.Base.PartialViewResult("Пользователь с логином не найден");
    }
}
```

Не использую метод RenderPartial() Так как взвывающее представление относится к контроллеру Group, а GetUser() относится к контроллеру Account.
Вот что возвращает в браузер при вызове представления выше:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Хелпер `Html.RenderAction` выполняет `GET` запрос. Уберите атрибут `[HttpPost]` с метода `GetUser`